# why "lidwake: 0" does not work?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, pmset

I have `MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)` and `OS: 10.13.6`

My pmset outputs:

```
$ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, Google Chrome)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         20
 acwake               0
 lidwake              0
```

You can see that I have set `lidwake` to `0`. But, I did two tests:

1, Close the lid, and then open the lid. The display and system just turned on.

2, `TopLeft Apple logo` --> Sleep --> Close the lid. Then open the lid. The display and system turned on again.

Why does this happen? I just want to prevent my macbook awake when I open the lid.

When it works, I think it will be awake only when I press any keys on the keyboard, is this right? If this is right, how to wake the system and display only when I press the power button? This is kinda second question. You can ignore the second question.

PS:

I found [link1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2699018) [link2](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/lidwake-0-not-working-brand-new-rmpb-13.1680135/) [link3](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23553087#23553087) [link4](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-disable-wake-from-sleep-on-open-on-mba-2011-lion.1233621/) having the same issue. And all the discussions end up no solution... What a pity!

Comment: did you use `sudo pmset lidwake 0`

Comment: @Buscar웃 yeah, actually, it's `sudo pmset -a lidwake 0`. I also did full shutdown and reboot to test. This never works.

Comment: does it even go to sleep with lid closed ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 that is another interesting topic. How do I know? I think it goes to sleep when the lid is closed. but who can tell? That is impossible to tell. At least, I don't hear the fans, I don't see any lights. I even use  → Sleep before closing the lid. I think it should be in a sleep mode. But who knows?

Comment: you can see it in the console

Comment: @Buscar웃 sorry, can you explain more what you mean by I can see it in the console? do you mean from terminal? do you mean I should run some programs in foreground and check if those program continue to run when I close the lid? I am not sure what you mean. thanks.

Comment: you know how to open the console, then just note the time when you close and open the lid, now it the console scroll back to those times and see what is it doing. or type Clamshell in the search

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks for the tip. I never knew there was a program called `console.app`. I did launch it and check. I can confirm that the macbook does go to sleep. During the 3 minutes, there is nothing running in the console.app. At the time when I open the lid, the `console.app` shows `system will power on`. So, the system does go to sleep, why doesn't `lidwake 0` do anything? The system will be auto on when I open the lid.

Comment: I need more investigation, as it stands right now something else is doing it and overriding it. You can try to `Log in as different user`  to see if it is user specific.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I am happy to provide any system information, command's outputs from terminal.app etc... But I really don't bother creating a new user for this issue. Do you have any ideas what may overriding this config? I tried `pmset -g` with and without power plugged, it always shows `lidwake 0`. I even turned off `Power Nap`. Nothing can make this work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Something is preventing your pmset, I just tried it on my High Sierra, and it accepts the change from 0 to 1 and reverse

Comment: @Buscar웃 when you say `it accepts the change`, do you mean the behavior is expected? My `pmset` command has no problem to set it from 0 to 1 and reverse. I can see the change from `pmset -g`. but the behavior is not expected. Thanks.